IEnumerator Not Taking Input Value
I'm making a turn based RPG in Unity and I have a slider that pops up when the player attacks. A runs down the slider and the closer the player gets the slider to the center and presses Z, the more damage it deals. However, for some reason, instead of it being a simple input, you either have to smash Z or it won't take the input at all.
Here's the code:
void DamageGauge(int target, float power, bool special, string status, string name)
{
    int t = target;
    float p = power;
    bool s = special;
    string st = status;
    string n = name;

    meterOpen = true;
    slashSlider.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    slashSlider.value = 0;
    StartCoroutine(DamageSliderTick(t, p, s, st, n));
}

// ReSharper disable Unity.PerformanceAnalysis
public IEnumerator DamageSliderTick(int target, float power, bool special, string status, string name)
{
    bool press = false;

    int t = target;
    float p = power;
    bool s = special;
    string st = status;
    string n = name;

    BattleChar sTarget = activeBattlers[t];

    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.01f);
        slashSlider.value += 4;
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) || i == 50)
        {
            float v = slashSlider.value;

            if(i != 50)
            {
                switch (v)
                {
                    case < 20:
                        DealDamage(t, p, .5f, s, st, n);
                        break;
                    case < 50:
                        DealDamage(t, p, .8f, s, st, n);
                        break;
                    case < 85:
                        DealDamage(t, p, 1, s, st, n);
                        break;
                    case < 97:
                        DealDamage(t, p, 1.4f, s, st, n);
                        break;
                    case < 132:
                        DealDamage(t, p, 1, s, st, n);
                        break;
                    case < 170:
                        DealDamage(t, p, .8f, s, st, n);
                        break;
                    case < 200:
                        DealDamage(t, p, .5f, s, st, n);
                        break;
                }
            } else
            {
                DealDamage(t, p, .5f, s, st, n);
            }
            

            slashSlider.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            slashSlider.value = 0;
            

            if (activeBattlers[t].currentHP <= 0)
            {
                RewardDialog.instance.xpPool += sTarget.xpWorth;
                RewardDialog.instance.moneyPool += sTarget.dollarWorth;
                if (sTarget.itemDrop[0] != null)
                {
                    RewardDialog.instance.ShuffleItems(sTarget.itemDrop);
                }
            }

            UpdateStatus(t);
            NextTurn();
            break;
        }
    }
}


You have to physically hit the Z button really hard? Unity wouldn't have any idea about how hard you press it. Sounds like an issue with your keyboard.

General hint: rather stick to your descriptive parameter names .. why would you store them in letter variables which only makes it harder to read? ;) I would then rather instead of writing DealDamage in multiple places, all basically with the same parameters except one, rather store this one parameter according to your cases and then call DealDamage in one single place right before slashSlider.gameObject.SetActive(false)

You could also wait directly in the Coroutine, just instead of using WaitForSeconds have a more manual wait loop like e.g.
for(var time = 0f; time < 0.01f; time += Time.deltaTime)
{ 
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    { 
        break; 
    } 

    yield return null;
}

This allows to track input every frame without missing one and directly interrupts the wait and continues with the rest when Z is pressed.

Despite that, a waiting of 0.01 seconds barely makes sense. For 60 FPS one frame takes about 1/60 = 0.017 seconds. So you could as well just use a
yield return null;

so it waits exactly one frame. Then instead of increasing the slider by a hard value per frame you could go by per second and do
slashSlider.value += 4 * Time.deltaTime;


Input.GetKeyDown will return true only if you press the key during that frame. Because you called it after WaitForSeconds, there is no guarantee that you just press the key at that frame.
Normally, you can call Input.GetKeyDown in the Update event method to record the time the key is pressed, and then compare the difference between the current time and the pressed time in the coroutine. If it is less than a certain threshold, it is considered that the player presses the key during this period.
// Update
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        zPressedTime = Time.time;
}

// DamageSliderTick
if ((Time.time - zPressedTime < threshold) || i == 50)
{
    ...
}


(in general I'm not a fan of mixing Update with Coroutines) I think in this use case it would actually be better to run the entire thing in Update right away .. would also allow to run the slider smooth instead of stepwise
